# Counting points numbers inside a rectangle in the matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I have uploaded an image which describes what I want to do. I have one plot and inside this plot I have rectangle. I want know how many points I have for the whole plot. and then how many points I have inside the rectangle. this will help me to make percentage. as its shown, the rectangle starts from x>1 and y>-50 ..

http://postimg.org/image/96w4s1x9t/

Comment: Can You post code of all the data sets including rectangle parametres? Simple script should iterate over element of each matrix and check if it's inside the triangle. Actually it has nothing to do with plotting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data are in matrces `x` and `y`, you can do something like the following

```
xRange = [1 7];
yRange = [-50 -20];

dataInRangeInd = (x >= xRange(1)) & (x <= xRange(2)) & (y >= yRange(1)) & (y <= yRange(2));
```

This creates a [logical index array](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) that you can use to extract the desired data points,

```
xDataInRange = x(dataInRangeInd);
yDataInRange = y(dataInRangeInd);
```

If you just want to know how many items are in the rectangle, you can just sum up the values in the index array, since it will have a value of `1` if the data point is inside the range and a value of `0` otherwise:

```
countInRange = sum(dataInRangeInd(:));
```

To get the total number of elements originally, you can use `numel`:

```
countTotal = numel(x); % or numel(y); whatever floats your boat
```

The percentage is then

```
rangePercentOfTotal = 100 * countInRange / countTotal;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you sooooo much. the problem is that I have a loop and I am applying your code inside the loop. so it will calculate only the percentage of one turn only. how can it calculate the percentage of all loops together ?!

Comment: I'd suggest making that into a separate question so you have the space to explain clearly what you need, because the question in your comment could mean any of a large number of things.